# SQL Agent alternatives for SQL Azure Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, agent

The [SQL Agent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) is [not available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/07/30/10044271.aspx) on SQL Azure Database. What is the recommended way to schedule routine jobs? I found [sqlazureagent](http://sqlazureagent.codeplex.com/) on codeplex, but I'm interested in what people have used in practice.

Answer (score 2):

- Recent updates on Azure have now provided add-on's that can be added to your Azure subscription and depending on your usage, it might be free or cost some money to you.

  - One such add-on is from Aditi Tech - Scheduler

  [image]
- Also, scheduler has been added to Mobile Services that will allow you to to create scripts that can run every X mins, days, hour or Months. This is well described on [**Create a new scheduled job**](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/schedule-backend-tasks/#add-job). A detailed example can be referenced from [Job scheduling in Windows Azure](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/job-scheduling-in-windows-azure)
- Depending on your need, you can even use the Windows Task Scheduler on Azure Virtual machines. You can use to schedule tasks just like same that you are used to on native Windows machines.
  An example can be found [here](http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2011/07/windows-azure-task-scheduler/) and [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/vinull/archive/2011/10/23/moving-to-azure-worker-roles-for-nothing-and-tasks-for-free.aspx).
- You can use a **worker role** to schedule and execute certain tasks at specific time using available frameworks like :

  - [TaskScheduler](https://github.com/Lokad/lokad-cloud/wiki/TaskScheduler) available at github.
  - [Building a Task Scheduler in Windows Azure](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/building-a-task-scheduler-in-windows-azure)
  - [Azure Tool Kit](http://azuretoolkit.codeplex.com/) from Codeplex.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the **Mobile Services Scheduler** within Azure itself. I was looking for this a while ago and came across this excellent [post by Sandrino Di Mattia](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/build-your-own-sql-server-agent-for-windows-azure-sql-database-with-the-scheduler/). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to use the SQL Agent for. Most of the SQL Agent jobs that I have seen in the past have been to schedule backups or SSIS packages. Neither of which is relevant in SQL Azure. SQL Azure backup scheduling is done through the Azure portal, and SSIS doesn't apply.

Other scheduled maintenance tasks that you may want to perform, such as rebuilding indexes, or moving data around, will need to be hand-rolled. I suggest you build a small app using ASP MVC Web API that has the scripts that you want to execute. You can run it pretty much for free as an Azure website if you need. Then call that service from an external scheduler. Kin's answer to your question provides some options. Personally, I use [setcronjob](https://www.setcronjob.com/), which suits our needs and costs me only $10 per year.

Perhaps provide specific examples of what you want to schedule in your question, so that solution-specific answers can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to schedule execution of stored procedures, our [Cotega](http://cotega.com/docs/sql_azure_scheduled_job) service might be of interest to you.